# Macros prefixed with 'with'

Tags: elisp, coding-conventions

Many emacs macros are prefixed with 'with' keyword in elisp. In an imperative language like python, `with` statement is used to create a temporary variable like this,

```
with controlled_execution() as tempVar:
     some code
```

However, in macros like `with-current-buffer, with-temp-buffer, with-temp-message`, i see `with` is not used for similar purpose. Can someone explain, in elisp macro, when to prefix a macro name with prefix `'with'`? And because these macros are expected to clear their temp variables, do they have any side effect on the main program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add a bit to what **phils** wrote. `with-` is usually an indication of resource management, so your initial guess was close (btw. Emacs Lisp is no less imperative language than Python). So, for example, `with-current-buffer` will enter and exit the specified buffer, i.e. *create* at start and *clean* afterwards. `with-output-to-string` will allocate a buffer where it will collect all output of the forms inside the macro.

The rationale behind these kinds of macros is that sometimes you don't want the user of your macro to deal with resource allocation and deallocation. So, such macros tend to have two distinct features:

1. They provide a variable bound during macro execution (the one which designates the resource being worked with).
2. They release acquired resources after the user code finishes.

A typical implementation would do something like this:

```
(defmacro with-something (var &body body)
  `(let ((var (allocate-var)))
     (unwind-protect ,@body
       (when var (deallocate-var)))))
```

Where `body` forms use `var` resource very similar to how in your Python code you could use the variable declared in `as var` part.

`with-current-buffer` is somewhat different since it doesn't expose the buffer variable, but calling buffer-related functions will be equivalent, so there's no real need.

Answer (score 7):

The thing the `with-` function have in common is that they create a code block where something, temporarily, has been changed. Once you have left the code block, things are back to normal.

By "code block" I mean a group of lisp statement grouped together with something that work like `progn`.

For example:

```
;; Do something in a buffer
(with-current-buffer another-buffer
  ;; do something in "another-buffer"
  ...
  ...)
;; Here, we're back to the original buffer
```

Another example:

```
(with-output-to-temp-buffer "*MyOutput*"
  ;; A "princ" prints to the newly created temporary buffer.
  (princ "Hello World!\n")
  (display-buffer (current-buffer)))
;; A "princ" here will print to whatever "standard-output" points to,
;; typically the echo-area.
```

Comment: hit the nail....

Answer (score 6):

Well just to be clear, `with-` as a prefix doesn't *do* anything. It is just a name, so *any* function or macro could be given a name starting with `with-` if you so wished.

The convention is that such a macro accepts a `&rest BODY` argument (i.e. some arbitrary number of forms), which will be evaluated in whatever context the prior arguments have established.

As there is nothing special about these macros, they may or may not have side-effects. Nothing is enforced. The documentation ought to make it fairly clear what each one does.

The naming scheme is intended to make for intuitive code. e.g. `(with-current-buffer BUFFER &rest BODY)` evaluates `BODY` with `BUFFER` set as the current buffer -- which is probably what you'd *expect* it to do if you saw the code and didn't already know.

Comment: And, for what it's worth, the `with-something-something-something` naming convention is also used in Common Lisp.  Both elisp and CL built on top of [Maclisp](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/elisp-manual-21/elisp_3.html), so I'm guessing the naming convention goes back at least that far.